# Put applications's public URL in its Docker Compose environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a Python API that has to know its public address to properly create links to itself (needed when doing paging and other [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) stuff) in the responses it creates. The address is given to the application as an environment variable.

In production it's handled by Terraform, but I also have extensive local tests that make use of Docker Compose. In tests for paging I need to be aware of the fact that I'm running locally and I need to replace the placeholder address I'm putting in the app's env with `http://localhost:<apps_bound_port>` for following the links.

I don't want to do that. I'd like to have a way to put the port assigned by Docker in the app's environment variables. The problem wouldn't be there if I was using fixed ports (then I could just put something like `http://localhost:8000` in the public addres variable), because I can have multiple instances of Compose running, which wouldn't work then.

I know I can [pass environment variables from the shell running docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substitute-environment-variables-in-compose-files) to the containers, but I don't know of a way to insert the generated port using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Only solution that I have for my problem now is to find a free port before Compose runs, and then pass it as an environment variable (`API_PORT=<FREE_PORT> docker-compose up`), while setting up the port like this in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
ports:
  - "8000:${API_PORT}"
```

This isn't ideal, because I run Compose both from the shell (with make) and from Python tests, so I'd need to put the logic for getting the port into an env variable in both places.

Is there something I'm missing, or should I create a feature request for Docker Compose?